# Wordpress page content not showing up

Tags: wordpress

I am using the latest nightly build **WordPress 3.0-beta2-14729** and the Theme TwentyTen. The content is not showing up where I indicated below. But when I go to the edit window, it is all there. Does anyone know what the problem is? The content in the edit box is ~400KB of text.

```
<div id="post-125" class="post-125 page type-page hentry"> 
<h1 class="entry-title">Post title</h1> 
<div class="entry-content">
// There should be something here
<span class="edit-link"><a class="post-edit-link" href="http://abp.bhc.com/wp-books-beta/aig/wp-admin/post.php?post=125&amp;action=edit" title="Edit Post">Edit</a></span>                  </div><!-- .entry-content --> 
</div><!-- #post-125 -->
```

the php code is:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you're hitting the memory limit/backtrace limit of the Preg Regular expressions on your server.

wpautop and wptexturize can sometimes hit it with larger posts.

Have a look at phpinfo() for pcre.backtrack_limit & pcre.recursion_limit (Report back on their size?)

You may be able to add this to your wp-config.php file:

```
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', '100000');
ini_set('pcre.recursion_limit', '100000');
```

And see if that helps? You could try upping the limits even further if it doesnt, just to test it.
(Note: Those values are what my default install has set, No idea if they're high enough, too high, or what)

Cheers,
Dion

Comment: Is that in bytes or kilobytes?

Comment: Neither. They're the number of times the regular expression library is able to backtrace, and the number its allowed to recurse, in a extremely simple expression, on a large peice of text, it'll only use very little, when you use a large piece of text, with a complex expression, it can often cause the backtracing to increase as it attempts to match the longer text.

Comment: Well, it didn't work, so I added another 0 to each number and then it worked. Thanks Dion. Also, how do I define this in php.ini?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, But according to google, this should do:
[Pcre] \newline\ pcre.backtrack_limit=1000000 \newline\ pcre.recursion_limit=1000000 (I added the 0 on there too btw)

Comment: For everyone's benefit I copied this from an email conversation on wp-hackers with Dion.

Comment: To be specific, it was the Backtrack limit that was set too low.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Only the title was showing, but everything was fine and present when editing.

Everything was working before, so I was hoping it would be a plugin conflict.  Which it was.

I had recently installed a few plugins to try for my new site. One of the plugins "Internet Marketing Plugin" was the culprit.  Once I disabled it, the problem was solved.

So, I'd suggest disabling any likely plugin to test it, look for anything that adds itself to your TINYMCE Editor panel or inserts stuff into the page on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

There are some stories in the WP forums of post text limits in WP because of server and WP memory limits, where the post title shows but not the post content, but no clear solutions. Try a smaller post ~50k or ~100K and see what happens.

Try to simply increase overall memory for WP by using `php_value memory_limit 64M`in .htaccess; or this near the top of your wp-config.php file: `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`  or this in your php.ini, if you have access to it: `memory_limit = 64M;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure is not still a draft your content? Is it published? Or is it static? I'm not seeing any embedded php code that should be inside entry-content.

Comment: No, the title is there and everything else except the content. I did check.

Comment: That is what is in the webpage when it goes to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred for me when I installed a duplicate of my main website to another directory to use as a dev environment.  I didn't do a clean install so I'm thinking it caused some file conflicts.

I tried using a different theme and was able to see page content.  So I deleted the theme I had problems with and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    if (/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        $('body').css('opacity', '1.0') 
    }
})
</script>
<style>
body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
</style>
```

add this two it works for sure, i  http://www.webdizer.com/